# Calling POST/SESSION in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple login page sending the user and pass via POST to the login.php and once the user and pass check against the database the user is sent to a page where a MySQL query is performed based on the username provided.
How do I call the POST method into the query?

index.php

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<input class='textbox' name='username'>
<input class='textbox' name='password'>
```

login.php

```
...
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$pword = $_POST['password'];
...
```

page1.php

Query to be performed:

```
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE userid= $TheUserFromindex/login.php"
```

Im being able to send a SESSION to page1.php for other uses but I dont know how to get the username into the query.

Comment: Do you wan'T to save and call Data from a Session? Then try to use Google

Comment: `WHERE userid= '$uname'`? Hard to say without seeing how you're using sessions with this.

Comment: Ist not good prectice to write the Variables into the String! Use the `.` Operator to connect Variables with Strings etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, after you verify the user's login credentials, you would set a session variable equal to something you could use to identify the user on later pages. That could be an ID, or the username itself.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

And then in your query, call:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE userid= $_SESSION['username']"
```

That should answer your question, but it's a rather stripped down, unsafe and naive approach. Also, never pass in raw post data to a MySQL query like that.

WikiHow has a good article that can show you how to create secure sessions and prevent XSS attacks or SQL injection:

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: I did try that solution before but kept getting a syntax error, guess it doesnt accept a variable like that.
Got it to work by sending the POST inside the SESSION and then assisgning a variable to that SESSION.
I do realize that its not the best code in the world, Im new to coding, still getting the kink of it.
Im just trying to get the basic idea working so I can improve on it later.